# Wordpress get content from another page and append it to active page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, wordpress, append, infinite-scroll

iam trying to create a infinite scroll in wordpress through appending content (seems the simples)

but the only thing that gets appended is 
"http://localhost/wptest/test2/ #content"

I´ve read quite a bit but didnt understand enough to solve the problem sorry :( .

Would someone be so kind to push me in the right direction?

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  alert( "test 1" );
  jQuery("#content").append("http://localhost/wptest/test2/ #content");
  alert( "test 2" );
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it finally^^,
it is actually quite simple: use the jQuery get function like this (for everyone who is searching):

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get("http://localhost/wptest/test2/").success(function(data){
        jQuery(data).find('#content').appendTo('#content');
    });
});
</script>
```